# In laravel data is not inserting into database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel and doing project using laravel framework please help me to solve this problem.

data is not inserting into table.

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('report/save','TestingController@store');
```

**TestingController**

```
 public function store(Request $request){
        $userId = \Auth::user()->id;
        $this->validate($request, [
            'from_stk_loc' => 'required',
            'testing_date' => 'required',
            'casting_date' => 'required',
            'debtor_no' => 'required',
            'concrete_grade' => 'required',
            'testing_age' => 'required',
        ]);

        $test_details['client_id'] = $request->debtor_no;
        $test_details['location'] = $request->from_stk_loc;
        $test_details['casting_date'] = $request->casting_date;
        $test_details['testing_date'] = $request->testing_date;
        $test_details['concrete_grade'] = $request->concrete_grade;
        $test_details['testing_age'] = $request->testing_age;
        $test_details['report_date'] = date('Y-m-d');

        $test_detailsId = DB::table('testing_report')->insert($test_details);


    }
```

**Model-> Testing.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Testing extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'testing_report';
    protected $fillable = [
    'client_id',
    'location',
    'casting_date',
    'testing_date',
    'concrete_grade',
    'testing_age',
];
}
```

Here is my form code, you can review this and find me a solution.

```
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">{{ trans('message.testing.client') }}</label>
            <select class="form-control select2" name="client_id" id="client_id">
              <option value="all">Select client</option>
              @foreach($customerData as $data)
          <option value="{{$data->debtor_no}}">{{$data->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
            </select>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="examplefromlocation">{{ trans('message.form.from_location') }}</label>
            <select class="form-control select2" name="from_stk_loc" id="from_stk_loc">
            @foreach($locData as $data)
              <option value="{{$data->loc_code}}" <?= ($data->inactive =="1" ? 'selected':'')?>>{{$data->location_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ trans('message.table.casting_date') }}<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
        <div class="input-group date">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </div>
          <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" type="text" name="casting_date">
        </div>
        <!-- /.input group -->
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ trans('message.table.testing_date') }}<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
        <div class="input-group date">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </div>
          <input class="form-control" id="datepicker1" type="text" name="testing_date">
        </div>
        <!-- /.input group -->
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="examplefromlocation">{{ trans('message.form.gradeofconcrete') }}</label>
           <input type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('message.form.gradeofconcrete') }}" class="form-control valdation_check" name="concrete_grade" value="">
      </div>
    </div>

       <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="examplefromlocation">{{ trans('message.form.testing_age') }}</label>
           <input type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('message.form.testing_age') }}" class="form-control valdation_check" name="testing_age" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- /.box-header -->
      <div class="box-body no-padding">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="purchaseInvoice">
          <tbody>

          <tr class="tbl_header_color dynamicRows">
            <th width="5%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.sno') }}</th>
            <th width="10%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.wt') }}</th>
            <th colspan="2" width="10%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.load') }}</th>
            <th colspan="2" width="10%" class="text-center">Comp Strength in M. Pa</th>
            <th width="15%" class="text-center">Avg Strength</th>
            <th width="15%"  class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.remark') }}</th>
            <th width="5%"  class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.action') }}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tbl_header_color dynamicRows">
            <th width="5%" class="text-center"></th>
            <th width="10%" class="text-center"></th>
            <th width="10%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.machine') }}</th>
            <th width="10%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.calibrated') }}</th>
            <th width="10%" class="text-center">7 Day's</th>
            <th width="10%" class="text-center">27 Day's</th>
            <th width="10%" class="text-center"></th>
            <th width="15%" class="text-center"></th>
            <th width="5%"  class="text-center"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="custom-item"><td class="add-row text-danger"><strong>Add Custom Item</strong></td><td colspan="8"></td></tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
      <div class="col-md-12">

        <a href="{{url('/sales/list')}}" class="btn btn-info btn-flat">{{ trans('message.form.cancel') }}</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat pull-right" id="btnSubmit">{{ trans('message.form.submit') }}</button>
      </div>
</div>
   </form>
```

**Problem:**

When I click submit button nothing is happening at all.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

---

This is view

```
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">{{ trans('message.testing.client') }}</label>
                <select class="form-control select2" name="client_id" id="client_id">
                  <option value="all">Select client</option>
                  @foreach($customerData as $data)
              <option value="{{$data->debtor_no}}">{{$data->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
                </select>
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="examplefromlocation">{{ trans('message.form.from_location') }}</label>
                <select class="form-control select2" name="from_stk_loc" id="from_stk_loc">
                @foreach($locData as $data)
                  <option value="{{$data->loc_code}}" <?= ($data->inactive =="1" ? 'selected':'')?>>{{$data->location_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{ trans('message.table.casting_date') }}<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
            <div class="input-group date">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" type="text" name="casting_date">
            </div>
            <!-- /.input group -->
          </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{ trans('message.table.testing_date') }}<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
            <div class="input-group date">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input class="form-control" id="datepicker1" type="text" name="testing_date">
            </div>
            <!-- /.input group -->
          </div>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="examplefromlocation">{{ trans('message.form.gradeofconcrete') }}</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('message.form.gradeofconcrete') }}" class="form-control valdation_check" name="concrete_grade" value="">
          </div>
        </div>

           <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="examplefromlocation">{{ trans('message.form.testing_age') }}</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('message.form.testing_age') }}" class="form-control valdation_check" name="testing_age" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <div class="box-body no-padding">
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="purchaseInvoice">
              <tbody>

              <tr class="tbl_header_color dynamicRows">
                <th width="5%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.sno') }}</th>
                <th width="10%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.wt') }}</th>
                <th colspan="2" width="10%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.load') }}</th>
                <th colspan="2" width="10%" class="text-center">Comp Strength in M. Pa</th>
                <th width="15%" class="text-center">Avg Strength</th>
                <th width="15%"  class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.remark') }}</th>
                <th width="5%"  class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.action') }}</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="tbl_header_color dynamicRows">
                <th width="5%" class="text-center"></th>
                <th width="10%" class="text-center"></th>
                <th width="10%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.machine') }}</th>
                <th width="10%" class="text-center">{{ trans('message.table.calibrated') }}</th>
                <th width="10%" class="text-center">7 Day's</th>
                <th width="10%" class="text-center">27 Day's</th>
                <th width="10%" class="text-center"></th>
                <th width="15%" class="text-center"></th>
                <th width="5%"  class="text-center"></th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="custom-item"><td class="add-row text-danger"><strong>Add Custom Item</strong></td><td colspan="8"></td></tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br><br>
          </div>
        </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="col-md-12">

            <a href="{{url('/sales/list')}}" class="btn btn-info btn-flat">{{ trans('message.form.cancel') }}</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat pull-right" id="btnSubmit">{{ trans('message.form.submit') }}</button>
          </div>
    </div>
       </form>
```

Comment: Let show what your variable $test_details current have ? By command dd($test_details) before your insert

Comment: do u get any errors?

Comment: please add $guarded = ['id'] in model . if you set id as auto increment

Comment: no.. its neither showing dd($test_details) nor errors

Answer (score 1):

To store data I would give your html elements name as db field and use simple:

```
$testing = new Testing();
$testing->fill($request->all());
$testing->client_id = $request->your_client_id_from_source;
$testing->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$testing->save();
```

So you will use directly laravel ORM and not raw db queries.

Comment: OP is using different column names, so this wont work, `debtor_no` is inserted as `client_id`

Comment: do you have any error message? Try to use my code step by step and don't only copy/paste...

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this problem by adding `<input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token" id="token">` in view page

Answer (score 0):

Your Model can only be used if your using **Eloquent Queries**. So based on your code your not using the model because your using  **Query Builder**

I have 2 suggestions:

1. Check your date format "date('Y-m-d')" make sure that mysql allow this.
2. Change your $request->from_stk_loc to $request['from_stk_loc'] and the rest if the codes.

Try again, let me know if that helps.

Comment: What about showing your html code? In order for us to figure out better.

Comment: Thanks, try adding this to your controller between $userId and store() and copy paste here the result.

dd($request->all());

Comment: NO error, its loading same page even though redirect path defined

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with everyone recommending Eloquent's ORM functionality over 'raw' DB queries.

As for a possible explanation: you are trying to insert into a non-fillable column: 'report_date', which might not be nullable in this table.

So try this in your model:

```
protected $fillable = [
  'client_id',
  'location',
  'casting_date',
  'testing_date',
  'concrete_grade',
  'testing_age',
  'report_date'
];
```

Comment: Does your table require it? in other words, is 'report_date' set to nullable?

Comment: That explains it perhaps. Your model is preventing 'report_date' to be sent, while your table requires it to be sent.

Does it help to add 'report_date' to your $fillable array in the model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use App\Model\Testing;

public function store(Request $request){
        $userId = \Auth::user()->id;
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'from_stk_loc' => 'required',
            'testing_date' => 'required',
            'casting_date' => 'required',
            'debtor_no' => 'required',
            'concrete_grade' => 'required',
            'testing_age' => 'required',
        ]);
        if( $validator->fails() )
        {
           return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        } else {
            $testingObj = new Testing;
            $testingObj->client_id = $request->client_id;
            $testingObj->location = $request->location;
            $testingObj->casting_date = $request->casting_date;
            $testingObj->testing_date = $request->testing_date;
            $testingObj->concrete_grade = $request->concrete_grade;
            $testingObj->testing_age = $request->testing_age;
            $testingObj->testing_age = $request->testing_age;
            $testingObj->report_date = date('Y-m-d'); // try date('Y-m-d H:i:s') if datatype is datetime
            $testingObj->save();                    

            $test_detailsId = $testingObj->id;    

    }
```

Comment: Now, What error you are getting? Could you please share?

Comment: in controller store() if i return 123; its not showing but its entering to store function

Answer (score 0):

please make  sure in model fillable fields are respective field is mentioned ,correct with no extra space accurately. In your model you have not mentioned report_date field.

```
namespace App\Model;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Testing extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'testing_report';
    protected $fillable
    = [
        'client_id',
        'location',
        'casting_date',
        'testing_date',
        'concrete_grade',
        'testing_age',
    //add this to the end.
        'report_date'
];
```